# No studs for glass shower door - Can I hollow wall anchor?

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile, ceramic-tile

I am looking to install a glass shower door using this frame.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Delta-48-in-to-60-in-Semi-Frameless-Contemporary-Sliding-Shower-Door-Track-Assembly-Kit-in-Nickel-SDLCS60-NIK-R/206195442

The glass is really heavy. The concern is I won't really be installing this door into studs. The vertical bar will be in studs but Most of the weight is in two collars that site on top and protrude about 1.5 inches from the vertical bar. Those collars have two anchor screws. They will sit next to the stud but not be on it.

https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/7b/7baa3fd5-f83d-4234-a27b-f1875b91010a.pdf

Page 22 through 24.

That section is a hollow back wall. I have tile and 1/2 inch cement board. No stud is available at that section. I called delta and they said I would need to purchase and use 3/16th inch tile anchors. They did not seem concerned with hanging these doors using anchors.

So two questions. Will it be safe to hang 75 lbs of glass door using 4 anchors? If so what type of 3/16 inch anchors would you use? When I search home depot there are a lot. I would prefer to get them at home depot. I am having my bathroom guys hang the door but I have to supply all the materials.

If it matters the anchor positions will be about half an inch from the studs.

Comment: why don't you ask your `bathroom guys`?   ...... are you saying that the stud is 1/2" behind the cement board?

Comment: The stud is about 1/2 inch to the side. There is no stud directly behind that offset part that holds the the top railing that holds the glass. So the vertical rail has a stud to drill into. This collar that sites on top of and in that vertical rail hangs offset almost an inch from that bar. So it will get some structural help from it but that majority of the weight will be on the anchors for that collar. Hard to explain. Easier to see in the PDF. I will talk to my contractor. I wanted to get a better idea myself so I understand what is going on and to make sure I have parts ready.

Comment: Its been a few years, but wondering if you had any issues.  I'm in the same boat.  The display images at home depot say a stud is "required", but the instructions tell you to use wall anchors.  I'm planning to use toggle bolts with an extra nylon sleeve.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can install it.   I would use a very rigid highly rated (100 lbs plus) toggle anchor and epoxy anchor to tile.

Honestly these screws aren't doing much.   Your side bar is sitting on shower pan, the top bar should not be loose, therefore pushing side bars, the screws literally just need to make sure the side bar stays on the wall/tile.   There may be some slight force against during shower door openings but nothing significant.   No issues at all with this install.

Comment: What @dmoore said ^^, but just a note about drilling tile near their edges. (Especially something hard like porcelain.) Use a small diamond grit hole saw like this one: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Milwaukee-1-4-in-Diamond-Plus-Hole-Saw-W-Arbor-49-56-0505/204994400  While you might be tempted to use a normal masonry bit, Murphy dictates that he'll make an example of you. (Ask me how I know!)